# QGIS - label points

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I am fighting with a proper displaying of fraction line in label of point.
I use expression of label
concat (  "ID" , '\n' ,' ',' ', '\n', "up"  , '\n' ,'⏤⏤⏤', '\n', "down"  )
Fraction line is a font marker.
The result is as follows.
[image]

Attributes "up" and "down" are decimal numbers with presicion of "2". However, as is seen at the label, in case of number "382,10" is displayed number "382,1". If a number is e.g."382,00", at the label it is displayed "382". Is it possible to have length of fraction line driven by lenght of numerator of a fraction? Alternatively, how to set a label that the number is displayed as "382,10", i.e. always with 2 decimal numbers? I used formatting-> formatted numbers-> decimal places=2, but it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Wait, are you asking about the fraction line, or are you asking about the decimal places?

Comment: Either solution works for me.

Comment: And what does "it doesn't work as expected" mean? Please include relevant attempts at expressions when talking about them.

Comment: When I used formatting-> formatted numbers-> decimal places=2, I expected that the result will be displaying of 2 decimal places in every labels. It isnt true, I dont know the result of this setting. I didnt find any difference "with" or " without" setting of formatting-> formatted numbers-> decimal places=2.

Comment: No, I didnt try. Now I wrote expression format_number("up",2) at checked "formatted numbers" and I tried the same at the column "decimal places" but with no result. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Decimal number (lenght=10, precision=2). Might be the problem that I manually moved labels?

Comment: I created new layer without manually moved labels and label is the same. Therefore the problem is not in manually moved labels. Where should I use  expression "format_number"?

Comment: It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To summarize the solution-finding process:

If you replace the simple `"up"` in your label with `format_number("up",2)`, the label will contain the values of the field `"up"` being forced to 2 decimal places. For further details, e.g. localisation aka "how does your decimal-separator look like", have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=format_number#format-number).